# click on button i send value to modal box but next this value send to the 2nd modal box its possible in core php?

Tags: javascript, php

```
 <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1" href="#">
          <lable target="_blank" class="passingID" data-id=<?php echo $mb['id'];?>>( Change Owner )</label>
        </a>
```

click on change owner button i opened one modal box and send value to that modal box but after click on 2nd modal box i want send value to also 2nd modal box

```
<script>
$(".passingID").click(function () {
   var ids = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $("#device_id").val( ids );
    $("#add_customer").val( ids ); //but here i want value print on front end i know its access in back end.
    
});</script>
```

this is the script. please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

data-id should wrapped in quotes , try this

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1" href="#">
    <lable target="_blank" class="passingID" data-id="label<?php echo $mb['id'];?>"  >( Change Owner )</label>
</a>
```

any back end result should updated after http request or Ajax

Comment: Thank u @Akram Elhaddad